# SpriteKit minimal energy

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a bouncing ball sprite with physics body.

```
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Constants.ballRadius)
    ball.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true

    ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.95
    ball.physicsBody!.mass = 1.0
```

The problem is that even when `restitution` is `0.95`, the ball stops bouncing too fast. It looks like it suddenly "sticks" to the border.

According to Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/restitution) about `restitution`

> This property is used to determine how much energy the physics body
>   loses when it bounces off another object. The property must be a value
>   between 0.0 and 1.0. The default value is 0.2.

So with every bounce my ball loses `0.05` of it's energy. So I think, that problem is that at some moment, it's energy becomes too small and `SpriteKit` decides to round it to `0`. But that moment comes too soon and it looks unrealistically.

What can I do to fix it?

**UPD:**

Here is my border's physics body:

```
 border.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(screenWidth, 10))
 border.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
 border.physicsBody!.restitution = 1.0
```

Comment: What's the restitution of the border? Try setting that to 1.

Comment: Make an complete example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @GrahamPerks as you can see in update, `restitution ` already equal `1.0`. @wangyudong, a add an update about border's physics body. There are no any physics objects on the scene.